# How to create a pagination for a dataframe?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I want to create a pagination system for my dataframe. I always create pagination with my queries but It doesn't work in dataframe. I cannot display on my template.
This is my views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(Case.objects.all().values(...)))
        query = df.assign(cnt=1).groupby([...)['cnt'].sum().reset_index()
        paginator = Paginator(query, 10)
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        if page_number == None:
            page_number = 1
        page_obj = paginator.page(int(page_number))
        print(page_obj) ----> <Page 1 of 33>
        context['query'] = query
        return context
```

And this is my template

```
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <tbody>
    {% for index, row in query.iterrows %}
    <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td>
            {{cell}}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Table shows nothing. How can I solve that?

Comment: At a first glance this doesn’t seem like the most optimal way of serving `Case` objects to html. Pagination or not, `pd.DataFrame(list(Case.objects.all().values(...)))` requires selecting all rows from the database.I don’t know from your question, what your query is trying to achieve, but chances are django’s ORM can make the query you need without pandas. I would suggest focusing your question on making the right query without using pandas and maybe the pagination will solve itself.

Comment: Please show how `Case` model looks like and what you want the query to be (especially what `groupby` does and what `assign` is meant to accomplish).